# Removing URL duplicates when using pretty urls

Tags: seo, friendly-url, http-redirect

I'm using pretty URLs in my web app, one example is 'forum/post/1' which invokes PostController in Forum module, which loads a post with id=1. This is what I need but that post is also accessible from 'forum/post/view/id/1'. That's bad, because search crawlers don't like when same page is accessible from several URLs, right?

I'm using Yii framework which supports 'useStrictParsing' option, which tells that incoming request **must** match at least one "pretty" route, otherwise request fails with 404. However it's not a perfect solution, because I don't have pretty URLs for every controller/action.

Ideally, framework should redirect 'forum/post/view/id/1' to 'forum/post/1' with a 301 status code. How did you solve this problem? It's not Yii/PHP specific question, how does your framework/tool deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to make sure search engines only rank one page the pretty url over another, if there are multiple ways to view the content is to your a canonical tag within the header of your document

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mydomain.com/nice-url/" />
```

This is very useful with windows based system as IIS is not case sensitive with its web pages but the web standard is case sensitive.

So

- www.maydomain.com/Newpage.aspx
- www.maydomain.com/newpage.aspx
- www.maydomain.com/NEWPAGE.aspx

These are all seen by Google as different pages, and you are then marked down for having a site with duplicate content, but not so with a canonical as each page in the case above would have the same canonical meta tag and the that url is the only one which will be used by the search engines.

Comment: OK I'll give it a try. I think it's xhtml-compliant?

Comment: I have now added a code example, yes its a standard html element so is xhtml compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that no one links to your non-pretty urls, the search engines will never know that they exist.

If you do want to eliminate them, you could bypass your web framework by adding an alias in you web server's configuration file; the url will be redirected before it ever reaches the framework.

Frameworks like Django, which don't provide 'magic' routing, don't face this issue, the only routes which exist are those which you define manually.  In it's case, you could define a view for the non-pretty url which returns the appropriate redirect.

Comment: > you could bypass your web framework by adding an alias in you web server's configuration file - you mean .htaccess?

Comment: The general configuration file for Apache is usually called apache2.conf or httpd.conf, and is kept where it is installed.  .htaccess files are used to override those configuration options for specific directories.  If you are using shared hosting, you may not have access to the general configuration file, but your host may provide a control panel to add aliases.

Comment: As I know aliases are for hostnames, e.g. alias.example.com points to example.com, isn't it? I need another thing: example.com/forum/post/view/id/1 must point to example.com/forum/post/1. I think it can be accomplished using mod_rewrite

Comment: You are refering to CNAME aliases used by DNS servers.  I am referring to aliases set up in your web server using mod_alias.  Mod_rewrite would also work, but it is more complex, and is not needed in this case.